# How to find the closest target given the start point coordinates?

Tags: java, math, path, distance

There are 2 targets in my game. I am using Breadth First Search to find the path to one of them. I want to know know how can I determine which is the closest target using their coordinates. I have X and Y coordinates of my targets (all int type).

```
 int result = 0;
 int target1dist = (playerX - target1x) + (playerY - target1y);
 int target2dist = (playerX - target2x) + (playerY - target2y);

 if (target1dist < target2dist){
     result = BFS(target1x,target1y,playerX ,playerY);
 } else {
     result = BFS(target2x,target2y,playerX ,playerY);
 }
```

This was not effective when the distance of one of the targets was negative. So I added absolute value function. So target1dist and target2dist cannot be negative.

```
int target1dist =Math.abs ((playerX - target1x) + (playerY - target1y));
```

Would this be a effective way to find the closest target so my AI player can direct towards it? P.S: My Ai player can only go 4 directions so diagonals are excluded. My other thought was to use Pythagoras to find the distance.

Comment: So the question was: does it work? I suggest it does (see my answer). Otherwise, you have some perfect code sample here (well, see about the initialisation of result in my answer too).

Comment: @Igor Yes it does. Thanks. But I wanted to know if there was an optimal solution for it. Better than my way of doing it.

Comment: Ok... I don't see how, except if you can approach your target "from behind" (making a hook). In this case, the target at closer distance can in fact be longer to reach than the other.

Answer (score 0):

With a slight modification your method should work. You don't want to take the absolute value of the full expression, but each component:

```
int traget1dist = Math.abs(playerX - target1x) + Math.abs(playerY - target1y);
```

This is called [Manhattan distance](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Manhattan_distance) and is a common measurement for tile based searches as yours. As Breadth-First-Search is [guaranteed to find the optimal solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search#Completeness_and_optimality) your solution will work.